# Unwanted vertical space before tabular on title page

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment

I worked on my title page, and there is some undesired vertical space before a tabular environment. I made two fboxes to illustrate the vertical distance I wanted to be the same 116 pt. But after the second box, a tabular environment starts and I assume it adds some vertical space before itself. This could be removed manually via \vspace*{-6pt}, but I am curious where does it come from?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\overfullrule=1mm
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}


\newenvironment{tightcenter}{%
  \setlength\topsep{0pt}
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
% \topskip= x pt  % 12 pt in scrreprt
\vspace*{12 pt} % so in effect 24 pt
\begin{tightcenter}
Title \\
Title more info \\
Title more info \\
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{116 pt}  \hfill\vspace{116 pt}\end{minipage}}\\
%\vspace{116 pt}
\Large\textbf{\textrm{Huge Title Huge Title Huge Title Huge Title Title Huge}} 
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{116 pt}\hfill\vspace{116 pt}\end{minipage}}
%\vspace{116 pt}
\end{tightcenter} 
% \vspace*{-6pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3.75cm}l}
& Advisor: & text text text\\ 
& More info: & text text text\\
& More info: & text text text\\
& More info: & text text text\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Can I somehow remove this space other than using a negative vspace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to suppress the vertical spacing around `tightcenter`, the best way is not using `center`

```
\newenvironment{tightcenter}
 {\par\centering}
 {\par}
```

Comment: this is better than before, but if you compare the distance from the last 'Title more info` to the first fbox, and from the second fbox to the line 'Advisor: ...' there is still a little difference

Comment: @TomM That's due to the `\strut` inserted by `tabular` in every row and the `\lineskip` glue.

Answer (score 3):

that is the default vertical skip *after* the center environment. Try:

```
[...]
}{%
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-\lastskip}%
}
[...]
```

Comment: you meant inside the `tightcenter` environment correct? That didn't change the vertical distance in the MWE

Comment: use a `\fbox` for the tabular and you'll see the difference! However, Enrico's solution is the better one.

Comment: great tip, I realized the remaining space comes from inside the tabular...so the only way to reduce this completely seems to be with the negative vspace.

Comment: Thanks again. I accepted his solution because you said it is better. Otherwise it would have been your call because you were first and both solutions are working.